# How to split up a fraction with a sum in the denominator?

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

How would you split up the fraction $$\frac{x}{a+b}$$ (or$$\frac{1}{a+b}$$)  so one fraction has $x$ and $a$ in it, only and another one has $x$ and $b$, only?

Comment: You generally don't.  The time where you might is if you have something like $\frac {a}{a+b} = \frac {a+b}{a+b} + \frac {-b}{a+b} = 1-\frac{b}{a+b}$  It might help if you had more details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So an answer doesn't exist?

Comment: There are endless algebraic manipulations you might perform, but none would be simpler than what you have. Again, what is your objective?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that last point so basically I wanted to take a series of $$\sum_{n=0}^{100} \frac{1}{a^n+b^n}$$ and split it into two sums. Sorry it took so long, I have to figure our how to use MathJax.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac 1{3+ 4} = \frac x3 + \frac y4$ where $x,y$ are integers?  .... in this case so that $\frac {4x + 3y}{12} = \frac 17$ or $7(4x+3y) = 12$.... can you say why there is not solution.

Comment: Your last  comment suggests that you have asked an xy question, which doesn't have a good answer. Perhaps you can delete this one and ask the real one instead, along with the work you have tried. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: hmmm. off the top of my head, I would say $a>b \implies \frac 12 \sum \frac 1{a^n} < \sum \frac 1{a^n+b^n} < \frac 12 \sum \frac 1{b^n}$ I will let you know if I get any better ideas.

Comment: @EthanBolker hmmm I'll make a second question then.

Comment: To add to previous comments / answers: if one of a,b is small, could approximate the fraction with Taylor's series terms around the other one (and then only that other one will appear in the denominator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac c{a + b} = \frac xa + \frac yb=$

Let $x$ or $y$ be whatever you want and solve for the other.

So if I say $x = 31$ we then have

$y = \frac {cba - 31(a+b)}{a(a+b)}$

And $\frac c{a+b} = \frac {31}a + \frac {\frac {cba - 31(a+b)}{a(a+b)}}b$

which is kind of stupid and pointless.

If you have a criteria that $x$ and $y$ must both be integers then

you have the condition that $ {\frac {cba - x(a+b)}{a(a+b)}}$ be an integer.

.... which can't always happen.  If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $c = 1$ the would require $(a+b)|ab$ which can't usually happen.

And if you *don't* have the criteria that $x, y$ be integers then... well, what's the point.

Now, we *can* probably do $\frac c{a+b} = \frac x{ak} + \frac y{bk}$ all integers but... why would we have a need to do that?

Comment: Thanks but what I meant was how do you separate them in therms of a, b, x with x and a on one part and x and b the other part.

Comment: "how do you separate them in therms of a, b, x with x and a on one part and x and b the other part."  I don't understand what that means.  You seem to be saying "how can I say $\frac 3{5 + 8} = \frac 35 + \frac 38$".  The answer is, of course, you can't.  Or are you saying "how can I do $\frac 3{13} = \frac 3x + \frac 3y$"?

Comment: First sorry for the spelling mistake. Two, I meant how do i take this $$\frac{x}{a+b}$$ and split it into two parts: one with x and a, the other with x and b.

Comment: "into two parts: one with x and a, the other with x and b."  I don't understand what that means.  You can't split $\frac x{a + b}$ to $\frac xa + \frac x b$ for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yeah i know that but how about any other way do split them.

Comment: He means if you have something divided by $a + b$, how do you convert into something divided by $a$ plus something divided by $b$.

Comment: "He means if you have something divided by a+b, how do you convert into something divided by a plus something divided by b. "  I know he meant that and I asnswered exactly that.

Answer (score 8):

If you have $x/(a+b)$, and you want to split it up then you can rewrite it like this. I assume here that the split will look something like $x/a + Y/b$:

$$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{Y}{b} = \frac{x}{a+b} $$

We solve for $Y$ to obtain:

$$Y = -\frac{b^2 x}{a (a+b)} $$

This given us:

$$ \frac{x}{a + b} = \frac{x}{a} - \frac{b x}{a (a+b)} $$

That may or may not be what you're after bt it one way to do it.

Comment: I don't know if that's what they were after but it's **exactly** what I needed right now. This lets me squeeze some calculation into 32 bit integers (with some assumptions about value ranges) that would have otherwise overflowed during the calculation... I have a=1, b=small fraction